# Missing last data to read from inputstream

Tags: java, android

I have seen all the answers related to this but that didn't work. I am reading an input stream data which is starting from STX and ending with ETX. I have used this logic. But didn't work. It always missing to read the last data.

```
public void getReportResponse() throws IOException {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( mmInStream ) )) {

           String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                // dataparse.Data(s);
                //   Log.i("DATA in getReportResponse", s);
                if (line.matches( "Scale id,Rec.No,Date,Time,Bill No.,Item No.,Plu,Name,Qty,Rate,Amount,Void" )) {
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        String t = line.trim();
                        dataparse.ReportData( t );
                       // addToTmpFile(line);// it will save Transaction report  content in txt file which is created in directory sotrage with folder Transaction.
                    }
                } 

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, run it through debugger or paste the sample data https://pastebin.com/ and share the link.

Comment: `which is starting from STX and ending with ETX` What do you mean? You are only reading lines. Nothing else. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please  tell which lines you are missing. Or what exactly?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat [link] https://pastebin.com/AyLj8qGR please check it pasted the sample data

Comment: The code is working fine. I have used this https://pastebin.com/raw/XwHau2Lq. You are probably not consuming the line.

Comment: Are you expecting to see `\u0002`(STX) and `\u0003`(ETX) as well?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat this logic not reading full data which is not showing full, If check this data with the serial terminal getting whole data. But using this logic the last row always missing.Actually, its dynamic data coming from Bluetooth

Comment: I would be able to help you out only if I could reproduce it on my machine. I think you will need to fix this on your own by taking help of debugger or asking a colleague.

Comment: yeah@AniketSahrawat i fixed it